# IPython Notebook display every line output without print

Tags: output, jupyter-notebook

I would like IPython Notebook to display every line output without explicitly using the print command. Example:

a, b, c = 1, 2, 4

a

b

c

would only display 4 in the output cell, but I would like it to display

1

2

4

Is there a way to do this? I would also be able to selectively suppress some lines (by using ;?)

Comment: Not  sure what you mean - works fine for me: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6086504/ipy.png

Comment: @alfasin, the question is reasonable. It's about ipython notebook :)

Comment: @cel maybe it's not a notebook, but it *is* an online version of IPython: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/

Comment: I am using IPython Notebook for Python 2, which runs in a browser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display full output in Jupyter, not only last result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786722/how-to-display-full-output-in-jupyter-not-only-last-result)

Answer (score 12):

The answer is

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

Type that on a cell, run it, and from then on each command will display its own output. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786722/how-to-display-full-output-in-jupyter-not-only-last-result)

[image]

If you don't want to see the output of a particular command, just end it with ";" [source](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tips.html)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but if you just want to see the output of multiple variables, you can list the expressions with comma in between: a, b, c would display 1, 2, 4