# How to display full output in Jupyter, not only last result--for R kernels

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786722/how-to-display-full-output-in-jupyter-not-only-last-result) is to install a python package.

What can one do if running an R kernel? R does not have Python magics.