# Explain working of following code in shell of jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have written following two codes in python in jupyter notebook.
I expect the output of code 1 to be same as the output of code 2. But I get different output.
Please help me to understand working of both the codes.

Explaining how shell output is different from compiled output is bonus.

## Code 1

`x = 2     # Line 1
 y = 2     # Line 2
 x==y      # Line 3
 x is y    # Line 4
 y is x    # Line 5`

## Code 2

`x = 2             # Line 1
 y = 2             # Line 2
 print(x==y)       # Line 3
 print(x is y)     # Line 4
 print(y is x)     # Line 5`

## Output of Code 1 :

`True`

## Output of Code 2 :

`True
 True
 True`

Answer (score 0):

By default the Jupyter notebook only outputs the last statement that was executed.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786722/how-to-display-full-output-in-jupyter-not-only-last-result) for a way to override.