# Show all error output lines in a Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm running a Jupyter Notebook with some code involving pySpark where I get a `Py4JJavaError` error as output.
This error is truncated, that means that I cannot see all the lines; the very last being a:

```
... 44 more
```

Is there a way to make the Notebook display *all* the output rows?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that's all the interpreter will print. Is it also the same case for other run cases?

You can try to run in a `debugging` mode.

```
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace
```

and

```
set_trace()
```

evokes a breakpoint. [source](https://davidhamann.de/2017/04/22/debugging-jupyter-notebooks/) You can also try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36835741/6505847) if it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this improved the output (more details in the error lines) but I still can not see all the lines

Comment: I am not able to find a straight answer on how this can be done on Jupyter. I also think this is because printing full error traceback would be enormous, sometimes it could involve 10+ files and this is just tedious with a lot of redundant info. You can though try this [method here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16946886/6505847)