# Why does Jupyter notebook NOT execute all the lines of code? (iPython)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

```
ls = [16, 81, 23, 74, 91, 612, 33, 812]

ls[2:6:3] #Starting from index 2 till index 5 and skip the next 2 indices
ls[::-1]  # Reverse list is printed
```

[image]

Only 2nd line i.e. `ls[::-1]` is executed. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Jupyter will only output the result of the last expression in a block. As you can see, all statements are executed. The second statement is executed, but the result is discarded, since it is not assigned to anything.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Thanks, but is there any way to get both being shown?

Comment: `print` them, or seperate into two blocks, or put both expressions on a single line (which will return a tuple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does execute all the lines, it only output the last one by default.
If you want to see all the steps, you can `print` the result you want to see.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786722/how-to-display-full-output-in-jupyter-not-only-last-result) also gives an alternative by asking jupyter to show all output systematically by adding

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please restart your jupyter-notebook again and also refresh jupyter. Hope its helpful..