# How to display all output in Jupyter Notebook within Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Within Jupyter Notebook in VS Code when I run code that prints a lot of output at some point the remaining output is suppressed and a message is displayed

"show more (open the raw output data in a text editor) ..."

How can I make all the output visible?

[image]

Comment: I think that's internally done and is not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786722/how-to-display-full-output-in-jupyter-not-only-last-result does this help

Comment: When you calculate really big numbers in IDLE, it compresses the data and asks user to display full output. I think that's done to prevent IDLE from becoming unresponsive

Comment: @Sujay, I will check out that link, but at first sight that is not what I am referring to. I mean I explicitly use the "print()" command and such print outs are done multiple times and upon reaching a certain number rows only the last content is shown. Similar to training neutal networks with tensorflow in jupyter, after a certain number Epochs, only the last one is shown. There seems to be a setting to limit the total number rows/pixels that are shown when outputting anything in jupyter...

Comment: @Sujay, I am happy to "open the raw output data in a text editor" but how can I do that. Clicking on the info message makes VS Code crash

Comment: ```from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell```
```InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"``` does this help

Comment: @Sujay, again, this above tip only helps with outputting data directly, such as putting "a" into a line, given a is previously defined. But it does not affect when explicitly printing via "print()". After a certain number of rows the remainder is cut, and the info message is displayed: "show more (open the raw output data in a text editor)"

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I think you are using the insiders build here is the right setting ,I had the same problem and it worked  for me.

```
"notebook.output.textLineLimit": 500
```

edit: this will also work for the stable version

Comment: Just to add to this. Open VS Code > File > Preferences > Settings. Then in the settings page look for "notebook". Scroll down and there's the "Notebook > Output: Text Line Limit", which by default has value 50 but can be increased. (VS Code 1.59.0)

Comment: I had to add this to my workspace text file like `"settings":  { "notebook.output.textLineLimit": 500 } `

Comment: worked for me after restarting vs code

Answer (score 10):

You need to change it from the settings. This is set lower value (30 in my case).
To see all lines, you need to change the "number of lines to show" value. Follow these steps to do so.

Open VS code settings or (ctrl + ,) >> In search box type "output.textLineLimit" >> Find "Notebook>Output: Text Line Limit" >> Change the value as per your requirement (say 500 to show 500 lines)

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of VS Code, the above-mentioned options can be found under Features->Notebook->Output: Text Line Limit

Answer (score -3):

set

```
"jupyter.textOutputLimit": 0
```

in the settings.json.

The default value of it is `20000`.