# Google Colab printing the output of only last line

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Initially I wrote the following code in Google Cloab -

```
import numpy
dir(numpy)
```

And ran the notebook it displayed a long list of strings like

> ['ALLOW_THREADS',  'AxisError',  'BUFSIZE',  'CLIP',
> 'ComplexWarning',  'DataSource',  'ERR_CALL', . .

Then I modified the code to

```
import numpy

dir(numpy)
speed = [99, 86, 87, 88, 111, 86, 103, 87, 77, 85, 86]

x = numpy.mean(speed)
print(x)
```

Now it just displayed the mean  - `90.45454545454545`
I am not sure why it didnt display the output for dir(numpy) now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display full output in Jupyter, not only last result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786722/how-to-display-full-output-in-jupyter-not-only-last-result)

Answer (score 0):

Because only prints are shown, or at maximum the last variables you are showing.

To fix it, add `print()` to `dir(numpy)`:

```
import numpy

print(dir(numpy))
speed = [99, 86, 87, 88, 111, 86, 103, 87, 77, 85, 86]

x = numpy.mean(speed)
print(x)
```