# Jupyter Notebook is not showing the output of any Python code executed on the cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have downloaded Jupyter Notebook to practice coding Python. My issue is that when I execute any Python code, the Out [ ] cell will never display. I have explored disabling all my antivirus software, and the issue persists. Is there some setting I have accidentally enabled??

I have attached a picture to illustrate the problem:

[image]

Comment: You gotta print the variable -> `print(c)` or just `c` should also work on jupyter

Comment: If you are doing a modification or defining a variable it won't display anything. In your image above if you had put just 'c' at the bottom it would have outputted 5. 

To avoid an auto output, you can add a ';' to the end of your statement. 'c;' will not output anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the Jupyter Notebook, You are not printing any of the variables. That's the reason it is not showing the output. Just add

```
print(c)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. But I thought that you didn't need to manually print (i.e. print ( ) command) variables in Jupyter - I thought the Out [ ] cell would show you the value without the manual command?

Comment: if you want something like that, then just put `c` in the end, it will print the c.

Comment: Oh I see!!! Thank you so much.

Comment: It says I don't have enough "reputation" to upvote. But it has recorded the feedback, and I sincerely thank you for your help!

Comment: Sure Please @ERhelpPlz01

Answer (score -1):

try `python -m ipykernel install --user` and then using the notebook again

Comment: This question does not require a reinstall or an install of ipykernel.

Answer (score -1):

Try to restart Kernal in jupyter notebook and it will give the output

Comment: Please don't resurrect old posts with advice that isn't pertinent to the posted case. While that is generally good advice to restart the kernel and try things, in this case, it would not have solved the 'problem' being reported. (I put 'problem' in quotes because there wasn't one. The OP misunderstood how the last expression is the only one special, [by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36835741/8508004), & assignments aren't expressions.) Did you run the code shown in the post in a new notebook and follow your own advice? You'd see that your 'solution' doesn't solve the posted 'problem'.