# Attempt to populate list with multiple entries in a for loop only returns a single entry

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with URLs I'd like to extract data from, but my script currently only manages to get the last entry to append. This is the script:

```
import os
import glob
import time
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
count=0
files=glob.glob('./extract/isbnlist/Reihe*_isbn-dnb2.csv',recursive=True) #searches all files in folder
print(files)

for file in files:
    if count==0:
        csvfile = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
        for row in csvfile['URL']:
            print('row: ' + row)
            with urlopen(str(row)) as response:
                doc = ET.parse(response)  
                root = doc.getroot()
                namespaces = {  # Manually extracted from the XML file, but there could be code written to automatically do that.
            "zs": "http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/",
            "": "http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim",
                }
            datafield_nodes_path = "./zs:records/zs:record/zs:recordData/record/datafield"  # XPath
            datafield_attribute_filters = [ #which fields to extract
            {
            "tag": "100", #author
            "ind1": "1",
            "ind2": " ",
            }]
            #datafield_attribute_filters = []  # Decomment this line to clear filters (and process each datafield node)
            aut = []
            for datafield_node in root.iterfind(datafield_nodes_path, namespaces=namespaces):
                if datafield_attribute_filters:
                    skip_node = True
                    for attr_dict in datafield_attribute_filters:
                        for k, v in attr_dict.items():
                            if datafield_node.get(k) != v:
                                break
                        else:
                            skip_node = False
                            break
                    if skip_node:
                        continue
                for subfield_node in datafield_node.iterfind("./subfield[@code='a']", namespaces=namespaces):
                    aut.append(subfield_node.text) #this gets the author name and title
                    
            print(aut)
        count+=1
```

and this is the csv file:

```
    URL
0   http://services.dnb.de/sru/dnb?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=ISBN%3D9783960382850&recordSchema=MARC21-xml
1   http://services.dnb.de/sru/dnb?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=ISBN%3D9783963622106&recordSchema=MARC21-xml
2   http://services.dnb.de/sru/dnb?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=ISBN%3D-&recordSchema=MARC21-xml
3   http://services.dnb.de/sru/dnb?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=ISBN%3D9783806241280&recordSchema=MARC21-xml
4   http://services.dnb.de/sru/dnb?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=ISBN%3D9783890296005&recordSchema=MARC21-xml
5   http://services.dnb.de/sru/dnb?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=ISBN%3D9783110699111&recordSchema=MARC21-xml
6   http://services.dnb.de/sru/dnb?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=ISBN%3D9783110698930&recordSchema=MARC21-xml
7   http://services.dnb.de/sru/dnb?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=ISBN%3D9783110699104&recordSchema=MARC21-xml
8   http://services.dnb.de/sru/dnb?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=ISBN%3D9783963621093&recordSchema=MARC21-xml
9   http://services.dnb.de/sru/dnb?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=ISBN%3D9783451716034&recordSchema=MARC21-xml
10  http://services.dnb.de/sru/dnb?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=ISBN%3D9788791953514&recordSchema=MARC21-xml
```

When I execute the script, the output is:

```
['Schmidt, Horst']
```

but I need the other results as well. How can I do that?
Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: link to the full csv file on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/YB0iC0kT) the filename is: Reihe-21A51.csv_extract.csv_isbn-dnb2.csv

Comment: I have added the `count==0` to limit the code to one csv only, as I have multiple csv in the folder and I don't want to wait 30 min only to see one result. I should've added a comment in the code to clarify the existence of `count`

Comment: Are you sure you posted the content of the *first* csv file? you should get a list (even empty) printed for every row, in this case 11...

Comment: yes, I did post the content of the first csv. Depending on where the `print(aut)` is put ( either in the `for row in` loop or outside, I get different results:
In the loop: row: `http://services.dnb.de/sru/dnb?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=ISBN%3D9788791953514&recordSchema=MARC21-xml
['Surname, Name']` for every row
outside the loop:
`['Schmidt, Horst']`

but what I need is a list with all results, not just the last one

Comment: my expected output would be like this:
aut=[Surname, Name,\n
        Surname2, Name2,\n
        Surname..., Name...]
which would then get put in a new csv

In this example, `"tag"="100"` didn't appear often, but it normally is present in every url

Comment: the first url doesn't have one, the second is `Bergren, Lisa Tawn`, the third has multiple (needs to be filtered out), the fourth is `Ritter, Karl-Markus` so my list should be: aut=[ , 'Bergen, Lisa Tawn', ..., 'Ritter, Karl-Markus']
Is this possible?

Comment: ... in place for the third entry which is faulty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244257/discussion-between-worldteacher-and-tranbi).

Comment: I ran your script and I get all names printed: `[] ['Bergren, Lisa Tawn']
['Rahlwes, Ann-Kathrin', 'Ortner, Helmut', 'Ladwig-Winters, Simone', 'Huonker, Thomas']
['Ritter, Karl-Markus']
['Kerkeling, Hape']
['Rohls, Jan']
['Rohls, Jan']
['Rohls, Jan']
['James, Bethan']
[]
['Schmidt, Horst']` don't know what's going on on your side (i commented out `#print('row: ' + row)`)

Comment: If you're using jupyter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786722/how-to-display-full-output-in-jupyter-not-only-last-result

Comment: ok, that seems to work, but can I somehow merge all the names into a single list that will be used later on?

Comment: sure, move `aut = []` outside of your loop

Comment: thanks a lot 

I have no clue how I didn't figure that out...  it's working perfectly now

Comment: @Tranbi side question: in case there is a blank [ ], how can I include a `None` in the list?

Comment: Comments are not designed for code support. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and feel free to create a new question

Comment: new question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72040032/how-to-append-none-to-list-if-result-contains-none-or-multiple-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tranbi pointed out, I had to move the aut=[] outside of the loop
it's now

```
for file in files:
    if count==0: #to only go through the first file, instead of all files in the folder
        csvfile = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
        aut = []
```

instead of

```
aut = []
            for datafield_node in root.iterfind(datafield_nodes_path, namespaces=namespaces):
```