# How to append None to list if result contains none or multiple results

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a csv with URLs which contain data I need to extract.
Sometimes, the URL contains none or multiple results, if that is the case, I want to append a `None`to the list.

This is the code:

```
import os
import glob
import time
from urllib.request import urlopen
from numpy import full
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
count=0
files=glob.glob('./extract/isbnlist/Reihe*_isbn-dnb21.csv',recursive=True) #searches all files in folder
print(files)

for file in files:
    if count==0: #to only go through the first file, instead of all files in the folder
        csvfile = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
        clean_aut = []
        title = []
        isbn_clean = []
        for row in csvfile['URL']:
            #print('row: ' + row)
            
            with urlopen(str(row)) as response:
                doc = ET.parse(response)  
                root = doc.getroot()
                namespaces = {  # Manually extracted from the XML file, but there could be code written to automatically do that.
            "zs": "http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/",
            "": "http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim",
                }
            datafield_nodes_path = "./zs:records/zs:record/zs:recordData/record/datafield"  # XPath
            datafield_attribute_filters = [ #which fields to extract
            {
            "tag": "100", #author
            "ind1": "1",
            "ind2": " ",
            }]
            #datafield_attribute_filters = []  # Decomment this line to clear filters (and process each datafield node)
            
            for datafield_node in root.iterfind(datafield_nodes_path, namespaces=namespaces):
                if datafield_attribute_filters:
                    skip_node = True
                    for attr_dict in datafield_attribute_filters:
                        for k, v in attr_dict.items():
                            if datafield_node.get(k) != v:
                                break
                        else:
                            skip_node = False
                            break
                    if skip_node:
                        continue
                for subfield_node in datafield_node.iterfind("./subfield[@code='a']", namespaces=namespaces):
                    clean_aut.append(subfield_node.text) #this gets the author name and title
        origdata=pd.DataFrame({'Author':clean_aut})                      
                    
        print(clean_aut)
        print(origdata)
        count+=1
```

This is the list file with the URLs: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/YB0iC0kT)

how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clean your code before posting it. It would be best to stick to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In your case you can remove the outer loop so that we can focus on the part causing problem.

About your code: you should set variables that are not modified during the loop *before* the loop. Also, checking attribute can be done with `any` which makes your code lighter. In order to add `None` to your list when no author is found, you can use a boolean:

```
namespaces = {  # Manually extracted from the XML file, but there could be code written to automatically do that.
    "zs": "http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/",
    "": "http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim",
        }

datafield_nodes_path = "./zs:records/zs:record/zs:recordData/record/datafield"  # XPath
datafield_attribute_filters = [ #which fields to extract
    {
    "tag": "100", #author
    "ind1": "1",
    "ind2": " ",
    }]

clean_aut = []
for row in csvfile['URL']:
    with urlopen(str(row)) as response:
        doc = ET.parse(response)  
        root = doc.getroot()
    no_aut = True
    for datafield_node in root.iterfind(datafield_nodes_path, namespaces=namespaces):
        if any(datafield_node.get(k) != v for attr_dict in datafield_attribute_filters for k,v in attr_dict.items()):
            continue      
        for subfield_node in datafield_node.iterfind("./subfield[@code='a']", namespaces=namespaces):
            clean_aut.append(subfield_node.text) #this gets the author name
            no_aut = False
    if no_aut: clean_aut.append(None)

origdata=pd.DataFrame({'Author':clean_aut})                      
            
print(clean_aut)
print(origdata)
```

Output:

```
[None, 'Bergren, Lisa Tawn', 'Rahlwes, Ann-Kathrin', 'Ortner, Helmut', 'Ladwig-Winters, Simone', 'Huonker, Thomas', 'Ritter, Karl-Markus', 'Kerkeling, Hape', 'Rohls, Jan', 'Rohls, Jan', 'Rohls, Jan', 'James, Bethan', None, 'Schmidt, Horst']

                    Author
0                     None
1       Bergren, Lisa Tawn
2     Rahlwes, Ann-Kathrin
3           Ortner, Helmut
4   Ladwig-Winters, Simone
5          Huonker, Thomas
6      Ritter, Karl-Markus
7          Kerkeling, Hape
8               Rohls, Jan
9               Rohls, Jan
10              Rohls, Jan
11           James, Bethan
12                    None
13          Schmidt, Horst
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'll try to implement the code into my program and see if anything works smoothly with a larger sample size