# Automatically display assignments in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there any kind of Jupyter magic to automatically echo/display/print assignments (like in Matlab):

[image: Matlab example]

It feels like such a waste of time to always have to do something like:

[image: Python example]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IPython Notebook display every line output without print](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31764006/6045800)

Comment: Tomerikoo, I am afraid [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31764006/6045800) is not what I am looking for. I would still have to explicitly access every single variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the Variable Inspector extension work for you?

Looks something like this..

[image: Jupyter Notebook with showing the Variable Inspector tab]

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for but definitely helpful. Thank you